# -webkit-text-stroke equivalent in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, editor, atom-editor, text-rendering

My text rendering in VSCode is blurry and I want to make it like my Atom text editor. In atom, the text rendering can be improved by controling `-webkit-text-stroke` and `-webkit-font-smoothing` property.

I wanted to know how to change these properties in VSCode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VS Code does not expose direct css styling like Atom does

Support for configuring `text-stroke` is tracked [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/17963)

You can also try the [`workbench.fontAliasing`](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/2577) setting.